# Race condition in multiple instance in kubernates

Tags: java, redis, race-condition

Hi i have a race condition in given method i have 2 instances in kubernates and checking in redis

```
public void method(GuestDTO guestDTO) {
    String executeName = "addingGuestToCache" + guestDTO.getUser();
    if (!redisService.checkExecute(executeName)) {
        redisService.startExecute(executeName);
        OpenGuestDTO openGuestDTO = new OpenGuestDTO();

        RMap<String, List<OpenGuestDTO>> openGuestDTOList = redisService.getOpenGuestDTOList();
        List<OpenGuestDTO> userGuestList = openGuestDTOList.get(guestDTO.getUser());
        if (userGuestList == null) {
            userGuestList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<OpenGuestDTO>());
        }
        for (OpenGuestDTO guestDTO1 : userGuestList) {
            if (guestDTO1.getGuestName().equalsIgnoreCase(guestDTO.getGuestName())) {
                redisService.deleteExecute(executeName);
                return;
            }
        }
        openGuestDTOList.add(openGuestDTO);
        openGuestDTOList.fastPut(guestDTO.getUser(), userGuestList);
        redisService.deleteExecute(executeName);
    }else{
        method(guestDTO);
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the race condition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.